# How to use multi term filter in Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I wish to implement the following rest api:

```
POST /t_source_item/_search?typed_keys=true&search_type=query_then_fetch
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.id": {
              "value": "1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.id": {
              "value": "2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the code I wrote:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery

val query = NativeQuery.builder().withQuery { q1 ->
    q1.bool { b ->
        b.filter { q2 ->
            q2.term { tq ->
                listOf(1L, 2L).forEach { t ->
                    tq.field("tags.id").value(t)
                }
                tq
            }
        }
    }
}.build()
val searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Book::class.java)
```

But I always only get the last `term` instead of multiple `term`, the rest api results are as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.id": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What should be the correct approach? I am using `spring-data-elasticsearch:5.0.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `forEach` with the tag ids to set the id of the same term query, that's why you see only the last value that was set.
You must use the loop to create separate filter queries:

```kotlin
val query = NativeQuery.builder().withQuery { q1 ->
  q1.bool { b ->
    listOf(1L, 2L).forEach { t ->
      b.filter { q2 ->
        q2.term { tq ->
          tq.field("tags.id").value(t)
          tq
        }
      }
    }
    b
  }
}.build()
```

alternate version using a range instead of a listOf:

```kotlin
val query = NativeQuery.builder().withQuery { q1 ->
  q1.bool { b ->
    for (t in 1L..2L) {
      b.filter { q2 ->
        q2.term { tq ->
          tq.field("tags.id").value(t)
          tq
        }
      }
    }
    b
  }
}.build()
```